# Update string of 'Sorry, ip_address has been banned' Drupal 7

Tags: string, drupal-7, message

How I can update message string from 'Sorry, ip_address has been banned.' to 'This website does not exist' for banned IPs? Without touching the core file 'includes\bootstrap.inc'

Comment: This should be better posted in the [Drupal Stack](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/). Have you tried searching the reference of that message variable or key throughout the whole application to see if it's the only value or if it's only a fallback if some message string does not exist in a file you can regulary edit?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. I have checked in few forums there the experts have commented that the only solution is to hack the core, but I dont want to. :Dlet me try my luck @DrupalStack as well.

Answer (score 0):

They are right, unfortunately if you want to change that text you'll have to edit core.

The alternative would be to not use Drupal's core IP blocking functionality and make your own/find a contributed solution

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I will check with few other modules to add on my own solution.